# Reorder format of string for i18n

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

e.g.

In English:

```
He used <Str_1> to <Str_2>
```

and in Chinese:

```
他对 <Str_2> 使用了 <Str_1>
```

How can I order this two `String`s (which are generated in code) differently for the code below?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",
         NSLocalizedString(@"Part1", nil),     // "He used" -> "他对"
         NSLocalizedString(str_1, nil),
         NSLocalizedString(@"Part3", nil),     // "to" -> "使用了"
         NSLocalizedString(str_2", nil), nil];
```

I happened saw a related question before, but unluckily, I can't find it now!
The workaround is something like `%2@` & `%1@` to do reorder, I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `localizable.strings` file:

```
"He used %@ to %@" = "他对 %2$@ 使用了 %1$@";
```

In code:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"He used %@ to %@", nil), 
    str1, str2];
```

This should re-order the string parameters.